# How to adjust one element to another in absolute position?

Tags: html, css, absolute

**What I wish to do:**

That the block element adjusts its height with respect to an element in absolute position.

**Problematic:**

If the price is too long, the price leaves the block.

**Conditions:**

- The block element must be clickable to go to the link.
- The price must not be in the link for referencing.

**What I've been trying to do:**

Make the price element clickable in javascript to go to the link and delete the absolute position, this solution was not chosen because you cannot do "CTRL + CLICK" to open in a new tab.

The case that works well:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  background: #3CAEA3;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.price {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <a class="link" href="https://google.com">
    <div class="title">Coffee table</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Made of wood</div>
  </a>
  <div class="price">
     The price is: 100€
  </div>
</div>
```

The case that doesn't work:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  background: #3CAEA3;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.price {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <a class="link" href="https://google.com">
    <div class="title">Coffee table</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Made of wood</div>
  </a>
  <div class="price">
     The price is tooooo long: 100€
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you have any solutions to my problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use absolute? Is flexbox an option?

Comment: Use flexbox if you are not concerned with old browsers. parent div will automatically resize

Comment: simply remove the fixed height (`height:20px`)

Comment: I don't really see how to do that.

The price element must be clickable, if I delete the absolute position it will no longer be the case. If I delete the 20 pixels of height, if the price is on 3 lines it will not be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

```css
.block {
  background: #3CAEA3;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.link,
.fakeLink {
  padding: 20px;
}

.link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fakeLink{
  opacity: 0;
}

.price {
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <div class="fakeLink">
    <div class="title">Coffee table</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Made of wood</div>
  </div>
  <div class="price">
     The price is tooooo tooo tooo tooo too long: 100€
  </div>
  <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com">
    <div class="title">Coffee table</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Made of wood</div>
  </a>  
</div>

<div class="block">
   <div class="fakeLink">
    <div class="title">Coffee table</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Made of wood</div>
  </div>
  <div class="price">
     The price is 100€
  </div>
  <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com">
    <div class="title">Coffee table</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Made of wood</div>
  </a>  
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  background: #3CAEA3;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.link {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.price {
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <a class="link" href="https://google.com">
    <div class="title">Coffee table</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Made of wood</div>
  </a>
  <div class="price">
     The price is toooooooo toooooo tooooo tooooo long: 100€
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace "The price is tooooo long: 100€" by "The price is toooooooo toooooo tooooo tooooo long: 100€" and it doesn't work. :'(

Answer (score -1):

I think using flex will solve your problem.

```
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  background: #3CAEA3;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.price {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
}

    <div class="block">
  <a class="link" href="https://google.com">
    <div class="title">Coffee table</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Made of wood</div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.apple.com/" class="link price">
     The price is tooooo long: 100€
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example the price is not clickable. :/

Comment: Please check it is clickable now

Comment: The link is clickable but it's not the same link as the block.

Comment: price link is now same as block

Comment: The whole block must be clickable and lead to the first link (google), this is not the case, the second link does not lead anywhere

Comment: the second link now leads to apple.com